# Iterating through a list of objects to assign a class attribute

Tags: python, list, class, loops

This is a snippet of a piece of code for a log parser I'm working on. The log parser is for a blade chassis and houses multiple blade servers.

I'm getting the following error from the for loop in blade_populate():

> "expected type integral got none"

What would be the correct way to iterate thru this object list, so that I can later have Python begin to populate firmware, such as the iDRAC?

```
def blade_create():
    blades= []
    for servers in range(blade_count()):
        blades.append(servers)
        return blades

blades = blade_create()

# Parse log to obtain FW revisions for blades

def blade_populate():

    for blade in range(blades):
        drac = log.readline()
```

Comment: Is the `return` statement in your first function really indented inside the loop? That doesn't seem like it could possibly be what you want. If you unindent it, you'll always return a list, even if `blade_count()` returns `0`. But you could probably just return `range(blade_count())` instead, rather than building a list yourself with a loop.

Comment: That was it, and my error cleared. I derped. Thanks for the call out!

EDIT: I can't give you credit for an answer, for some reason, it may be because of my status.

Comment: You couldn't accept it because it's a comment (I wasn't sure if it was a typo copying the code over to Stack Overflow, or a real issue). I've expanded it into an answer below.

Comment: Thanks again, dude. I've got a lot to learn, but I'm a hell of a lot better now than I was a few months ago. As far as accepting goes, I figured that was the case, but I'm also not 100% how limited my permissions are all the time, considering my reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an indnetation error. The `return` statement in your function is inside the loop. That means it either gets hit when the loop runs the first iteration, or if the loop doesn't run at all (because the range is empty), it doesn't `return` at all (which in Python is equivalent to doing `return None`).

To fix it, unindent the `return` statement one level:

```
def blade_create():
    blades= []
    for servers in range(blade_count()):
        blades.append(servers)
    return blades                              # unindent here!

blades = blade_create()

# Parse log to obtain FW revisions for blades

def blade_populate():
    for blade in blades:     # this line shouldn't use range if blades is a list
        drac = log.readline()
```

I'd note however that your `blade_create()` function is equivalent to `range(blade_count())` (with perhaps `list(...)` wrapped around it if need to be able to modify the result later). It may be that you don't need a separate function for that at all.